# Working with azure(mysql database) in node javascript with cloud API

Tags: mysql, node.js, git, mongodb, azure

I'm working with an API app on Azure by deploying an API written in NodeJs which stores data in MongoDb.

1. Make a new API for web & mobile apps from Azure portal.
2. Choose MongoDb by adding MongoLab module from Azure.
3. Create a table (collection) and populate it with few entries.
4. Prepare our Git repository from Azure portal and link it to our local Git on computers.
5. Decide which NodeJs modules to use to set the dependencies.
6. Edit the configuration file for NodeJs.
7. Make the main API file with the following functionalities:

   ```
      Connection to the database.

      Running the service.Making CRUD operation services (CREATE, READ,DELETE...)

      Testing our API on a browser.

      Making an application using our API
   ```

My question: how to use these steps to store data in mysql database(azure)?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fully understand your requirement, do you want to use the MySQL database to store your data in your API application in Node.js? If not, please clarify your purpose.

To implement connection to MySQL in Node.js, you can use some 3rd part MySQL handler modules.

For example:

[node-mysql - A pure node.js JavaScript Client implementing the MySql protocol](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)

or

[Sequelize - A promise-based ORM for Node.js and io.js](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/)

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.